# Unexpected failed dependencies when uninstalling a package using RPM

Tags: redhat, rpm

When checking for packages that depend on a particular package (in this case `lz4`) using `rpm` it does not list any packages that require either `lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.i686` and `lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64`...

```
# rpm -q --whatrequires lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.i686
no package requires lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.i686
# rpm -q --whatrequires lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64
no package requires lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64
#
```

But I can't uninstall either of them without using `rpm --nodeps` as they appear to be needed by `systemd` and/or `systemd-libs`.

```
# rpm --erase --allmatches lz4
error: Failed dependencies:
        liblz4.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) systemd-libs-219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64
        liblz4.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) systemd-219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64
        liblz4.so.1 is needed by (installed) systemd-libs-219-57.el7_5.1.i686
#
```

It looks like the output of `rpm --whatrequires` is wrong but is it? (I doubt that it is actually wrong - but I don't understand why doesn't it include `systemd` or `systemd-libs`?

I thought if using `rpm --erase --test` instead of `rpm --whatrequires` to identify if packages that have dependencies but is there another more reliable way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bit tricky. `rpm --whatrequires` tracks **capabilities**; not simply packages.

If you try again; you will see that:

```
rpm --whatrequires "liblz4.so.1()(64bit)"
```

will provide you the results.

`rpm --erase --test` seems a good way to go for me. An alternative would be to loop over the capabilities provided by the package that you want to remove; but that will be slower. Here is a small bash script that loops over the capabilities of lz4 and prints the packages who depend on those capabilities:

```
packageToRemove=lz4
for capability in $(rpm -q $packageToRemove --provides | awk '{print $1}')
do
    echo "packages requiring $capability:"
    rpm -q --whatrequires "$capability"
done
```

Comment: Very useful but not quite there yet - the results for `lvm2` and `lvm2-libs` are difficult to interpret (I'd post the output but can't format it in a comment).  Using `rpm --test` it becomes clear that `lvm2` depends on `lvm2-libs`.

Comment: my script is just a demo script; just to indicate how the capabilities work. Your use of `rpm -e --test` seems faster and easier to me (as I said in my answer). afaik there is no more reliable way.

Comment: I'll go with that... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following command gives me the result I was expecting though I still don't yet understand why `rpm --whatrequires` doesn't work. (I probably won't figure that out until I build my first package).

```
# repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires --cache --installed lz4
systemd-0:219-57.el7.x86_64
systemd-libs-0:219-57.el7.i686
systemd-libs-0:219-57.el7.x86_64
#
```

In some cases however the output can be *"interesting"*...

```
# repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires --cache --installed lvm2-libs
lvm2-7:2.02.177-4.el7.x86_64
lvm2-libs-7:2.02.177-4.el7.x86_64
# 

# repoquery --whatrequires --cache --installed lvm2
lvm2-7:2.02.177-4.el7.x86_64
#
```